# undefined to get nested obj

Tags: javascript, json, object

i have value name='dropshiper.name', i want to get error from this errors[name], but the output is undefined.

```
console.log(errors);
output:
{
    "email": {
        "type": "required",
        "message": "",
        "ref": {}
    },
    "dropshiper": {
        "name": {
            "type": "required",
            "message": "",
            "ref": {
                "value": ""
            }
        },
        "phoneNumber": {
            "type": "required",
            "message": "",
            "ref": {
                "value": ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i'm stuck, help me, other way i using is erros.name, still undefined

i expecting is the output is errors.dropshiper.name

```
const name = 'dropshiper.name'
console.log(errors[name]); //output: undefined
console.log(errors.name); //output: undefined

console.log(errors.dropshiper.name); //output: {
                                                "type": "required",
                                                "message": "",
                                                "ref": {
                                                  "value": ""
                                                 }
                                               }
```

i want output like errors.dropshiper.name, but i want using variable name

Comment: The string “dropshiper.name” can be used as the key of an object, as obj does not have a 'dropshiper.name' key value pair, so the corresponding value cannot be found.